# Plotting an filled line chart with 4 variables against a 5th variable ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a postion="fill" which represents an allocation on the y axis (to always sum to 100) and another variable on the x axis. Variable 1-4 are numeric integers, variable 5 is also numeric. Variable 5 is a continuous numeric. All five variables on are on the same row.

Y axis: variable 1 + variable 2 + variable 3 + variable 4 = 100
X axis: variable 5

Is there a way to do this without melting my data table?

Sample code, caution: runs a bit slow due to how I set up variables 1-4...

```
library(combinat)
combinations <- combn(100, 4)
permutations <- combinations[, colSums(combinations) == 100]
rm(combinations)

data <- t(rbind(permutations, 
  replicate(ncol(permutations), cumprod(1+rnorm(20, 0.05, 0.30))[20])
))
```

Comment: Why don't you want to melt your table?  Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: I could probably melt it, but was curious if there was a way to do it more directly without that feature. I don't really have a reproducible example, but you can just imagine a dataframe with 1000 observations of 5 variables, where variables 1-4 sum to 100 and are all integers between 1 and 100, and variable 5 is continuous between 0.8 and 1.0

Comment: Downvote is for " ...don't have a reproducible example, but you can just imagine ...". The implication is that we should make the example for you.

Comment: I know this is old, but I added some code to provide a data frame that fits the question. In any case, these days I just got used to using melt

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate a reproducible example would be

```
set.seed(1)
data_ex <- data.frame(t(rmultinom(1000,prob=rep(0.25,4),size=100)),
                       v5=runif(1000,0.8,1))
```

and then

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(reshape2)
 ggplot(melt(data_ex,id.var="v5")) +
    geom_area(aes(x=v5,y=value,fill=variable))
```

draws the plot.

If you *really* want to do things the hard way you can avoid using `melt`, but `melt` is much (much much) easier!

```
 cumvals <- t(apply(data_ex[,1:4],1,cumsum))
 data2 <- data.frame(cumvals,v5=data_ex$v5)
 ggplot(data2,aes(x=v5)) +
    ## these must go in reverse order
          geom_area(aes(y=X4),fill="green")+
          geom_area(aes(y=X3),fill="purple")+
      geom_area(aes(y=X2),fill="red")+
      geom_area(aes(y=X1),fill="blue")
```